# Rmarkdown journal template rendering inverted exclamation mark (¡) in table, while .tex has correct less than symbol "<"

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm writing a paper using the ACM manuscript latex template in Rmarkdown. I have a table including p values, which have been formatted with scales::pvalue() to get the < symbols in there instead of long almost-zero numbers.

The problem I'm having is that even though in the .tex file that gets produced from my Rmarkdown has the correct symbol, it still gets rendered as (¡) on the pdf.

I'm aware this is probably related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2369/why-do-the-less-than-symbol-and-the-greater-than-symbol-appear-wrong-as, but as the class I'm using as part of the template already uses T1 font encoding, I'm at a loss for how to solve this.

I am also unable to recreate the problem in overleaf. Pasting what the latex script for the table into https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/acm-conference-proceedings-primary-article-template/wbvnghjbzwpc works as expected.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] of your rmd file?

Comment: Hi, yes the repo is here https://github.com/gjpstrain/naughty_latex_min_rep

That contains everything to knit the pdf that contains the error in a table.

Comment: Works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/9szpI.png

Comment: Is your latex distribution up to date?

Comment: I've tried it with my home and work computer, both using tinytex 0.41. Still having no luck - I've had several other people try it, also getting the same output with the repo that I posted.

Are you compiling with something other than tinytex?

Comment: I don't have tinytex, I'm using normal texlive2022. Do you have access to the .log file? This should tell you which version of latex you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that there was a TinyTex package missing - I compiled with MikTex and it worked, so then I ran `tinytex::install_yuhui_pkgs()` and it finally worked.

Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz for your help.